# How to avoid TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Tags: javascript

How can I avoid this error? It works, but I've always seen this error, here is the code:

```
function Separe(price) {
    nStr = Number(document.getElementById(price).value) * 100
    nStr += '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(nStr)) {
        nStr = nStr.replace(rgx, '$1' + ' ' + '$2');
    }
    return nStr + " Centimes"
}

function Forma(price, dest) {
    var handler = function(e) {
        document.getElementById(dest).innerHTML = Separe(price)
    };
    document.getElementById(price).onchange = handler; //line 50
    document.getElementById(price).onkeyup = handler;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<input id="prix" type="number" name="prix" min="1" step="1">
<script>
    Forma("prix", "hhh"); //profil 148
</script>
<h1 id="hhh" >&nbsp;</h1>
```

My page is issuing an error on load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null formatter.js:50
Forma formatter.js:50
(anonymous function) profil:148
```

I did it to avoid to put twice `onchange` and `onkeyup`

The variable is not yet made, this is the cause of the error, but how do I avoid it? I tried even to add all variable and initialise them as nulls, but still getting the error!

Comment: where? i dident quote it in the main function because i use it several times with different `id`

Comment: Put the full function definition up. It is missing a closing `}` and doesn't look like it is inside a function.

Comment: Your function just kind of trails off... do you have a closing `}` somewhere, that you didn't include in your pasted code?

Comment: @meagar I was reading bottom-up, where it looks like global scope.

Comment: modifed the variable name to avoid confusion

Comment: Instead of changing the variable name, you should post the rest of your function and correctly indent the body. That would go much further towards avoiding confusion.

Comment: sorry, i'll reformat the code

Comment: Holy crap. The problem is that you're leaving the closing `}` on the last line of the function, in both functions. **Never do that**. Several experienced programmers attempting to help you *totally* missed the presence of the closing `}`. This should be a pretty good indication that you've stumbled upon a coding style that is to be avoided.

Comment: the latest `}` is for the end of the function `Forma`

Comment: `document.getElementById(price)` - you have to make sure this element always exists, if it doesn't then you'll keep getting the nulls.

Comment: @limelights yes, that what i did, i declared the value in the beginning and dident work, added `document.getElementById(prix).value = "0"` and dident work, even added `<input ... value="0">`and still dident work

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barney/XKxpX/ — no errors being reported if I just cut and paste your code. Try to see what line number the error is being reported on — maybe the problem is elsewhere in the code?

Comment: @Barney the code works, but signals this error in Chrome,

Comment: No error being signaled in Chrome if you load that link where I copied and pasted your code. When Chrome reports the error, it should provide a link back to the line in the code where the error is happening — you should then be able to put a breakpoint in and debug. Where is that line?

Comment: @Barney i added the error, the javascript will works fine, but  dont call it until the event, what i tried is to add the value but dident work.

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp that's not even the error in your question.

Comment: @limelights is right — there's no property `value` anywhere in the code you've presented: the error is happening elsewhere. But next to that there's the number 47. Click that number and Chrome will show you the line where the error is occurring. Honestly, without you doing this there is no way we can help you.

Comment: this happened after added `function Forma(prix, dest) {
    document.getElementById(prix).value = "0"` to try to add an initialized value, after removing it, i got the error in the line ` document.getElementById(prix).onchange = handler;`

Comment: i think i'll go with the direct way and add the triggers in the  html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that i was a duplicate function in the code!
the  page uses accordion effect, and the function is called twice (buy area, and sell area), and it was bizarre that even the `id` were different, the code alerts errors; but ONLY THE  FIRST CALL WORK, NOT THE SECOND.

in the second it was an id different:

```
<script>
Forma("hh", "max");
</script>
```

....

```
<script>
Forma("h", "min");
</script>
```

what i did, is to change to second to

```
<input .... onkeyup="document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = Separe('min')"  onchange="document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = Separe('min')"/>
```

and it  worked! now Chrome dont alert me even that the first section (buy) will call the function as in my question!

Comment: sorry, because when i wrote the answer it said that i have to wait, then the connexion cut (africa here)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can avoid this error entirely is by having the element you're asking for ready in the DOM when you query for it.

Assume you have this HTML:

```
<span id="monkey">Hey I'm a monkey</span>
Result for hopeful monkey:<span id="result"></span>
Result for not so hopeful monkey:<span id="noresult"></span>
```

and this javascript:

```
var hopefulMonkey = document.getElementById("monkey");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hopefulMonkey;

var notSoHopefulMonkey = document.getElementById("noMonkeys");
document.getElementById("noresult").innerHTML = " "+notSoHopefulMonkey;
```

The output would be:

```
Hey I'm a monkey 
Result for hopeful monkey:[object HTMLSpanElement] 
Result for not so hopeful monkey: null
```

You're therefore trying to access an element that obviously doesn't exist yet or at all if you're getting that error.

That said, you have something else that's causing your trouble since the code you've posted works in Chrome. What version are you running?

I made a fiddle of your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/EqtQz/

I made a fiddle demonstrating my answer as well: http://jsfiddle.net/vB2Jp/1/ (it has monkeys so it's fun too!)

Comment: It's pretty clear in his markup that he's calling the function immediately after  declaring the element in question in the markup — but then his code doesn't actually produce the error if you output it anyway.

Comment: i'm on `Version 26.0.1410.64 m` and the value will not existe untill i `onchange` or `onkeyup` and i tried `onload` but dident work

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp well, your code works you have something else that's bugging. What's on line 47 of your formatter.js?

Comment: this happened after added function Forma(prix, dest) { document.getElementById(prix).value = "0" to try to add an initialized value, after removing it, i got the error in the line ` document.getElementById(prix).onchange = handler;`